# Two Weeks in Cambridge (England), practicing sport in group

Tags: europe, england, cambridge

In January, I am going to be in Cambridge for 2 weeks to attend a school to improve my English skills. I'm searching for things to do during the weekends, and since my goal is to improve my English, I'd like to do activities involving groups.

I like sport and wild activities, so it would be fun to find a good organization that organises sport or walking events during the week.

Any other ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a shopping question, which isn't usually allowed on travel.se BUT, since there is only one thing everybody visiting Cambridge should do, I'll answer. What everybody should do when visiting Cambridge is Punting.

[image: Punting picture] (Source: [Wikicommons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cambridge_-_Punting_in_Cambridge_-_1690.jpg))

What to do else really depends on personal preference. I would suggest to resort to Travel guides (e.g. Guide Routard, Lonely planet, etc) or sites like Tripadvisor for ideas.

Comment: Punting in January may not be the best idea, given the weather (not that I have a better suggestion).

Comment: You just need to wrap up warm, and maybe take a thermos of warm winter pimms rather than normal pimms + lemonade, but other than that it's still fun!

Comment: Thank you for your answer , It's not a shopping question , i search a website or organization to have group sport activities like that http://www.adrenaline-project.com/sejour-sport-extreme-sensation-surf.html (French) but near cambridge :)

Comment: @L.Quastana a "shopping" question doesn't always mean buying things, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/185482#185482 for more

Comment: @KateGregory I did not know this term :) Thank you.I will know for next time